# Aligned pgfplots in beamer frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spacing, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to reproduce the design represented in the following picture with
`Beamer` an `Pgfplots`.

[image]

Namely, I want the size of plotting area to be always the same size
and have the same position whatever the axis label and graduations are
and the text bellow it is.

Here is my current attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{table/row sep=\\}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\imglarg}
\newlength{\imghaut}
\setlength{\imglarg}{0.9\textwidth}
\setlength{\imghaut}{0.6\textheight}

% ====
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
      \pgfplotstableread{
        1 4.3\\
        2 4.2\\
        3 3.1\\
        4 2.5\\
      }\tablea
      \begin{axis}[%
        /pgfplots/table/header=false,
        width=\imglarg,
        height=\imghaut,
        axis on top]
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=1]{\tablea};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \vskip0pt plus 1filll%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item You must defeat Sheng Long to stand a chance
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% ====
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
      \pgfplotstableread{%
        1000000 3500000000\\
        2000000 3800000000\\
        3000000 4000000000\\
        4000000 3000000000\\
      }\tableb
      \begin{axis}[%
        /pgfplots/table/header=false,
        width=\imglarg,
        height=\imghaut,
        axis on top]
        \addplot table[x index=0, y index=1]{\tableb};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \vskip0pt plus 1filll%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Xyzzy !
  \item Nothing happens.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It only works if there are no different *random graduations taking
some space* (for instance if both graph are plotted using \tableb).
I ended here after substantial trial and error so i am far from sure
that every piece of code there is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you encounter is due to the bounding box.

The bounding box is made so large that it encompasses all content within each `tikzpicture`.

The workaround is to set the same bounding box for each of the pictures. This will make them locate the same place in the presentation (as long as the code is consistent).

Ok, so it can be solved by resetting the bounding box of the tikzpicture and *fixing* it in each of the frames.

This can be done as follows:

```
\pgfresetboundingbox % clear the bounding box
\path (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
```

However, this will align along the axis lines. And any axis descriptions are outside the bounding box. If you have a very tightly packed slide you need to include those in the bounding box. To do this across two plots which does not have the same description you have to set the enlarged explicitly.
This might not always be the preferred way. A solution is to use the calc library and shift the position:

```
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path ($(current axis.south west)-(.5cm,.5cm)$) rectangle 
    ($(current axis.north east)+(.5cm,.5cm)$);
```

The above will take the axis lines and make the bounding box 0.5cm larger in each of the 4 directions.

A complete example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{small,height=5.25cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%

\def\MyAlign{%
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
}
\def\MyAlignCm#1{%
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path ($(current axis.south west)-(#1cm,#1cm)$) rectangle 
    ($(current axis.north east)+(#1cm,#1cm)$);
}

Following two frames are aligned:

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[
      xticklabel=\relax,
      yticklabel=\relax,
      domain=-2:2
      ]
      \addplot {x^2};
      \addplot {x^3};
      \addplot {x^4};
    \end{axis}
    \MyAlign
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}
}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[
      title=A title,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      domain=-2:2
      ]
      \addplot {x^2};
      \addplot {x^3};
      \addplot {x^4};
      \legend{$x^2$,$x^3$,$x^4$}
    \end{axis}
    \MyAlign
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}
}%

\vspace{.5cm}
Following two frames are aligned:

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[
      xticklabel=\relax,
      yticklabel=\relax,
      domain=-2:2
      ]
      \addplot {x^2};
      \addplot {x^3};
      \addplot {x^4};
    \end{axis}
    \MyAlignCm{.5}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}
}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[
      title=A title,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      domain=-2:2
      ]
      \addplot {x^2};
      \addplot {x^3};
      \addplot {x^4};
      \legend{$x^2$,$x^3$,$x^4$}
    \end{axis}
    \MyAlignCm{.5}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}
}%

\end{document}
```

This will yield the following output:

[image: Notice the alignment]

I will leave it as an exercise to use `\phantom` to aquire the same result without resetting the bounding box.

Comment: Changing the bounding box is a problem when using the externalization library : the axis labels and ticks non longer appears.
The MyAlignCm version you proposed allows to sidestep this problem but one has to `measure' the space needed by the labels and adapt the command in consequence making it less powerful.
I do not know the `\phantom` command but it might solve this issue?

Comment: If you use externalize, everything becomes more complicated. The easiest thing is to use `\MyAlignCm` until it fits. Phantom could prove useful though. Look the command up and see what it does. Then the hint is to make complete identical plots with every label, title, xtick etc. enclosed in a phantom.

Comment: This might be cumbersome as well. Redefining \MyAlign with four arguments makes it quite tractable. Thanks for you help!

Comment: If you want to modify the bounding box *and* use the `external` lib, you should resort to `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline]`. This will introduce suitable negative hspaces *without* really truncating the BB. The `baseline` option causes vertical alignment at the baseline of surrounding text - perhaps that helps as well.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the result obtained by altering bounding box with the method you suggested. Maybe some other paramameters I am using messed it up but as my presentation is soon due I cannot investigate right now.

Comment: @AlfredM. it must then be related to other content on the frames. The bounding box will align as i have shown if they are empty. Try in two empty frames.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant that I succeeded with the `bounding box` method but not the `baseline` one.
THe `baseline` one works indeed with empty frame but I need to add text in some frames and none in other (as in my drawing). It is possible by altering the bounding box provided that there is not too much text.